# Liapunov 's Direct Method $(S.L.Ross )$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Autonomous Non-Linear system

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = P(x,y),$$

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = Q(x,y).$$

Assume that the given  system  has an isolated critical point  $(0,0)$. Let $P \text{ and }Q$ have  continuous first partial derivatives $\forall (x,y) \in D$.

Also consider these definitions for reference:

> > Stable critical point :
> >
> > Let $C$ be  the path of the given System ; $x(t) = f(t) \ \ and \ \ y(t) = g(t)$ be a solution of the given system , Define $$ D(t) = \sqrt{[f(t)]^2 + [g(t)]^2}$$ denote the distance between the   critical point $(0,0)$ and the point R:$[f(t) , g(t)]$. Then the critical point $(0,0)$ is stable if for every number $\epsilon > 0$, there exist a number $\delta > 0$ such that the following is true . Every path $C$ for which $D(t_0) < \delta$ for some value $t_o$
> >     is defined for all $ t > t_o$ and is such that $$ D(t) < \epsilon \text{ for }t_0  \leq t < \infty.  $$
> >
> > 13.10 Theorem
> >
> > Consider the above non linear  system . If there exist a Lipunov function $E$ for the given System in some domain $K$ containing $(0,0)$, then the critical point $(0,0)$ is stable.

Proof :

In the text, the author proved that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that for any path $C : x(t) = f(t) \text{ and } y(t) = g(t) $ satisfies the following:

$$ E[f(t_0) ,g(t_0) ] < \delta  \text{ for some } t_0$$

and

$$   E[f(t), g(t)] < \epsilon \text { for }  t_o  \leq t < \infty  $$

and says $(0,0)$ is a stable critical point

According to the definition of stable critical point, how can we show that

$$ D(t_0) < \delta  \text{ for some } t_0,$$ 
$$ D(t) < \epsilon  \text{ for }  t_0  \leq t < \infty.$$

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: @ daOnlyBG : Thanks for editting.